# Spark scala finding value in another dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Hello I'm fairly new to spark and I need help with this little exercise. I want to find certain values in another dataframe but if those values aren't present I want to reduce the length of each value until I find the match. I have these dataframes:

```
----------------
|values_to_find|
----------------
|    ABCDE     |
|    CBDEA     | 
|    ACDEA     |
|    EACBA     |
----------------
------------------
|  list    | Id  |
------------------
|  EAC     |  1  |
|  ACDE    |  2  |
|  CBDEA   |  3  |
|  ABC     |  4  |
------------------
```

And I expect the next output:

```
--------------------------------
| Id  | list  | values_to_find |
--------------------------------
|  4  | ABC   |      ABCDE     | 
|  3  | CBDEA |      CBDEA     |
|  2  | ACDE  |      ACDEA     |
|  1  | EAC   |      EACBA     |
--------------------------------
```

For example ABCDE isn't present so I reduce its length by one (ABCD), again it doesn't match any so I reduce it again and this time I get ABC, which matches so I use that value to join and form a new dataframe. There is no need to worry about duplicates values when reducing the length but I need to find the exact match. Also, I would like to avoid using a UDF if possible.

I'm using a foreach to get every value in the first dataframe and I can do a substring there (if there is no match) but I'm not sure how to lookup these values in the 2nd dataframe. What's the best way to do it? I've seen tons of UDFs that could do the trick but I want to avoid that as stated before.

```
df1.foreach { values_to_find =>
        df1.get(0).toString.substring(0, 4)}
```

Edit: Those dataframes are examples, I have many more values, the solution should be dynamic... iterate over some values and find their match in another dataframe with the catch that I need to reduce their length if not present.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can load the dataframe as temporary view and write the SQL. Is the above scenario you are implementing for the first time in Spark or already did in the previous code ( i mean before spark have you implemented in the legacy system). With Spark you have the freedom to write udf in scala or use SQL. Sorry i don't have solution handy so just giving a pointer.

Comment: It is for the first time. yeah, I want to avoid using a UDF, not sure if I could use map with some conditions to iterate over the values I need to find

Answer (score 0):

the following will help you.

```
 val dataDF1  = Seq((4,"ABC"),(3,"CBDEA"),(2,"ACDE"),(1,"EAC")).toDF("Id","list")
 val dataDF2  = Seq(("ABCDE"),("CBDEA"),("ACDEA"),("EACBA")).toDF("compare")


 dataDF1.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")
 dataDF2.createOrReplaceTempView("table2")

spark.sql("select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.list like concat('%',SUBSTRING(table2.compare,1,3),'%')").show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+-------+
| Id| list|compare|
+---+-----+-------+
|  4|  ABC|  ABCDE|
|  3|CBDEA|  CBDEA|
|  2| ACDE|  ACDEA|
|  1|  EAC|  EACBA|
+---+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Hello, I have many more values in the dataframes, I can't use a contains or like in a sql function, I might duplicate something. I was thinking more about doing some sort of map with conditions inside to iterate over the values I need to match.